# Docker Windows container can't resolve host.docker.internal

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-container, docker-desktop, windows-container

My windows docker container cannot resolve *host.docker.interna*l, but it's working with Linux containers.  I would prefer to stay with Linux containers, but I am having trouble with an old .Net framework 4.7.2 application.

My application connects to RabbitMQ on the local machine.  This works as expected in the Linux containers, but with the windows container it throws this error:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known

I've tried pinging host.docker.internal.

> C:\app>ping host.docker.internal   Ping request could not find host
> host.docker.internal. Please check the name and try again.

Here is my dockerFile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
COPY ${source:-SampleApp/obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\app\\SampleApp.exe"]
```

I am using docker version **20.10.2**, and docker desktop version **3.1.0**.
I'm running on Windows 10, version 10.0.18363.

Comment: Were you able to fix it ?  Me too facing the same issue.  Kindly answer your own question and let us know how the issue was fixed

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue in a roundabout way. In my docker-compose.yml file, I created a network and bound a static IP as the gateway ip like below

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  service-name:
    networks:
        local_net:
            ipv4_address: 172.18.0.2
networks:
  local_net:
    ipam:
        config:
           -
            subnet: 172.18.0.0/25
            gateway: 172.18.0.1
```

After this, in my docker file, I added the below command

```
RUN $file = $Env:windir+'\System32\drivers\etc\hosts'; '172.18.0.1 host.docker.internal' | Add-Content -PassThru $file;
```

And it is working like a charm for me now.